# How do I remove the undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

If the user does not have a first, middle, or last name, it will show an undefined. How can I remove the underline but instead I will put a saying that it they need to click this link to update their profile
[image]

```
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const mapState = ({ user }) => ({
  currentUser: user.currentUser,
});

const Settings = () => {
  const { currentUser } = useSelector(mapState);

  const name =
    currentUser?.firstName +
    " " +
    currentUser?.middleName +
    " " +
    currentUser?.lastName;

  return (
    <>
       <Typography>Hello, {name}</Typography>
    </>
  );
};

export default Settings;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const mapState = ({ user }) => ({
  currentUser: user.currentUser,
});

const Settings = () => {
  const { currentUser } = useSelector(mapState);

  const nameComponents = [
    currentUser?.firstName, 
    currentUser?.middleName,
    currentUser?.lastName
  ].filter(part => Boolean(part));
  const name = nameComponents.join(" ")

  return (
    <>
       <Typography>Hello, {name}</Typography>
       { nameComponents.length !== 3 && <button @click="...">
         Fill lackink parts of your name
       </button>}
    </>
  );
};

export default Settings;
```

Comment: Safer than mine..\

Answer (score 2):

You can do a simple checking while rendering `Typography` component as below

```js
  return (
    <>
       {(
          currentUser?.firstName && 
          currentUser?.middleName && 
          currentUser?.lastName
        ) 
        ? <Typography>Hello, {name}</Typography> 
        : <div>whatever </div>
    </>
  );
```

Comment: Probably currentUser is defined, but do not has one of his names.

Comment: @Daniel, the solution based on OP's comment `but instead I will put a saying that it they need to click this link to update their profile `

Comment: Ok. I checked. `undefined, undefined, undefined` in this case can be signal that `currentUser` is also `undefined`. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Map and/filter the values

Assuming currentUser ONLY has firstName, lastName and middleName

We need more testing if there are roles or addresse etc

```js
const currentUser = { "firstName" : "John", "lastName": "Doe" }

const names = Object.values(currentUser).map(name => name || "");
console.log(names.join(" "))
console.log("Fullname?",names.filter(name => name).length >= 2)

// destructing is not useful here
// const { firstName, middleName, lastName} = currentUser
// console.log(firstName, middleName, lastName)
```

Comment: You can have unpredictable results in this approach. For example:

`currentUser = { "lastName": "Doe", "firstName" : "John" }`

or 

`currentUser = { "firstName" : "John", "lastName": "Doe", "role": "admin" }`

Answer (score 0):

Use conditions. Return component  `<Typography>Hello, {name}</Typography>`  if user has at least all required properties, else redirect to the profile update component.